# Can't align container to the top of page and center it horizontally

Tags: flexbox, vuetify.js

This is my code:

```
<template>
  <main>
    <v-container grid-list-xs class="text-xs-center">
      <v-layout row>
        <v-flex xs2 v-for="n in 6" :key="n">
          <v-card tile class="pa-1" dark color="error">
            <v-card-text>
              Some mildly interesting thing #{{ n }}
            </v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
      <v-layout row>
        <v-flex xs12 >
          <v-card tile class="pa-2" dark color="secondary">
            <v-card-text>
              Well, that's interesting too!
            </v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
        <v-layout row>
          <v-flex xs2 v-for="n in 6" :key="n">
            <v-card tile class="pa-1" color="warning">
              <v-card-text>
                And something more here #{{ n }}.
              </v-card-text>
              </v-card>
            </v-flex>
          </v-layout>
        </v-layout>
      </v-container>
    </main>
</template>
```

When `<main>` is in use, I get the view with all flex items vertically aligned to the top, which is my goal, but they're not aligned to the center horizontally, there's a gap on the right-hand side (where the question mark shows in the 1st picture).

When I remove `<main>` from the code and the `<v-container>` becomes the parent element, the items go to the center, horizontally and vertically (2nd picture).

Again, I need them v-aligned to the top and centered horizontally. How to achieve this?

[image: Layout with <main> engaged.]
[image: Layout without <main> section]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace your main tag with a v-content tag. I had this same issue. If you are using Router wrap router-view in a v-content tag rather than a main tag. You can find examples in Vuetifys' docs [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/layout/pre-defined)

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need **fill-height** on the v-container and possibly a **fluid** as well.

```
<v-container fill-height grid-list-xs class="text-xs-center">
```

Comment: Unfortunately, these parameters don't change the position, they just stretch the contents to the sides creating a one-line layout. So far, I'm adding another <v-layout row> with blank contents at the bottom, so that it could push the non-empty rows towards the top. However, it feels more like a workaround than an exact solution.

Comment: You can probably get help from "Community > Chat & Support" at https://vuetifyjs.com/vuetify/quick-start I've gotten a few helpful answers there.

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

```
<v-container fill-height justify-start>
```